# Find upper bound for T(n) in terms of n and prove with Master Theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, analysis-of-algorithms

Sorry about the formatting. Had nothing but my cellphone!

**Problem**: Suppose this is an algorithm that runs in T(n) time, where T(n) is the following recurrence relation:

T(n) =

- $2T($$ \frac n3$$) + Θ(n),  x > 2$
- $Θ(1), x ≤ 2$

Draw a tree and find the upper bound of T(n) in terms of n. Prove upper bound using Master Theorem.

**My tried solution**: The recursion tree that I ended up with;

Levels

1. n
2. $$ \frac n3 \frac n3 $$
3. $$ \frac n9 \frac n9 \frac n9 \frac n9 $$
4. .....
5. $$(1) (1) ... (1)$$

Work for each level.

1. n
2. $$ \frac n3 + \frac n3 = \frac 23n$$
3. ...
4. k nodes. Since 2T, I got $2^k$ with work $$\frac {n}{3^k}$$, which
   in the end would be $$ \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^kn $$

Since there are $$log_3 (n)$$ levels, I ended up with $$n = \frac{n}{1-\frac{2}{3}} = 3n$$

EDIT: which in the end would be O(n).

When I try to prove this using Master Theorem, I can't for the life of me get it to work for any of the 3 cases.

For example, for case 1: I try to prove T(n) ≤ c*n and my end result is T(n) ≤ $$\frac 23n + n $$

Is my tree completely wrong or is my understanding of the master theorem wrong?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The master theorem gives you a condition to check to determine which case to use; you don't get to pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the critical exponent is $\log_32$ and $f(n)$ is $\Omega(n^{\log_32})$, only the third (supercritical) case of the master theorem applies and we have to use the regularity condition
$$2f(n/3)\le\color{blue}{\frac34}f(n)$$
on $f$ to get that $T(n)=\Theta(n)$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'm still confused as I thought the Master Theorem case 1 was for O, case 2 for Ω and case 3 for Θ, and the question asked for upper bound.

Comment: @BenD The master theorem always gives you $\Theta$ bounds (when it applies). That's why it's so useful.

Comment: That explains it! Thank you so much

Comment: @BenD Won't you accept/upvote my answer?

Comment: I did, sorry for the delay. Thanks again!